# Please provide example for web3.eth.sendTransaction

Tags: web3js

I created a contract (in the Ropsten Test Net) for the most basic example described in this article:
http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/introduction-to-smart-contracts.html

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract SimpleStorage {
    uint storedData;

    function set(uint x) {
        storedData = x;
    }

    function get() constant returns (uint) {
        return storedData;
    }
}
```

The following Javascript calls that contract:

```
var abi = [{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"x","type":"uint256"}],"name":"set","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"get","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}];
var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);
var myContractInstance = MyContract.at('0x51a5846DB9DEb1Cd72ccab36F825C06328a21b8C');

myContractInstance.set.call(1, function(error, result){
    if(!error) {
        console.log("#" + result + "#")
    } else {
        console.error(error);
    }
})

myContractInstance.get.call(function(error, result){
    if(!error) {
        console.log("##" + result + "##")
    } else {
        console.error(error);
    }
})
```

The "set" call does not work, because it requires "sendTransaction" instead of "call".

I have tried every combination of parameters in web3.eth.sendTransaction, and I continually get the following error message: 
"sendTransaction Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function"

I have read the API documentation (https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API), which does not provide a good example for web3.eth.sendTransaction.
Please do not provide just a theoretical explanation, or a requirement to install additional tools.

Please provide a specific javascript code example that has been tested, to show how I can use just javascript to execute the "set" function in the contract shown above.

Answer (score 2):

You can directly call `set` function, like this :

```
myContractInstance.set(2,{from:eth.coinbase}, function(error, result){
    if(!error) {
        console.log("#" + result + "#")
    } else {
        console.error(error);
    }
})
```

Or call `sendTransaction` function, as follows:

```
myContractInstance.set.sendTransaction(1,{from:eth.coinbase}, function(error, result){
    if(!error) {
        console.log("#" + result + "#")
    } else {
        console.error(error);
    }
})
```

Hope it helps~

Comment: Why does your example show "from:eth.coinbase"? I am using Ropsten Test Net.

Comment: You can replace `eth.coinbase` with `you account address` , like this, `myContractInstance.set(2,{from:"0x0b46c35d2e823f9b1e69ff616f9e9bf2d9d52dd0"}, function(error, result){
    if(!error) {
        console.log("#" + result + "#")
    } else {
        console.error(error);
    }
})`

Comment: Is there any advantage of "set" vs. "set.sendTransaction"? Do both methods incur the same gas cost?

Comment: There is a 30 second lag between the "set" and the "get". Can you provide some simple JS code to show how my program can wait for the confirmation before executing the "get"?

Comment: "set.sendTransaction" costs more lesser. when calling `set` function, you must wait for being mined, only mined, this transaction would be valid. If your `get` depends on `set` logic, like this :

Comment: `myContractInstance.set.sendTransaction(1,{from:eth.coinbase}, function(error, result){
    if(!error) {
        //console.log("#" + result + "#")
        myContractInstance.get.call(function(error, result){
            if(!error) {
                console.log("##" + result + "##")
            } else {
                console.error(error);
            }
        })
    } else {
        console.error(error);
    }
})`

Comment: I don't know what you meant by "costs more lesser", Does "set" cost less, or more,  than  "set.sendTransaction"?

Comment: `set` would cost more gas than `set.sendTransaction`

Comment: I would like to avoid hard-coding the "from" address. Is there a generic term that returns "the user currently logged into MetaMask", or what is the best way to get the address of the user currently logged in?

Comment: You should deal with `address` according to your logic. For example, someone logged and you saved `his address`, and then regard it as a param to transfer to `set.sendTransaction` function.

Comment: What is the best way (from Javascript) to get the address of the user currently logged in to MetaMask?

Comment: Sorry, i'm not familiar with MetaMask~